# PyPlot deleting arc

Tags: python, matplotlib

The code given below is supposed to plot 2 arcs and then delete an arc.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import patches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import matplotlib

xcenter=300
ycenter=300
angle=0
k=0
p=[100,155]
theta=[1.0471975512, 1.0471975512]
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
plt.axis([0,600,0,600])
ax.grid('on')
plt.ion()
#plt.ion()
S=2
num_ellipse=[]

while k<S:
    if k==0:
        e=patches.Arc((xcenter, ycenter), p[k], p[k], 0.0, 0, theta[k]*(180/math.pi))
        ax.add_patch(e)
        num_ellipse.append(e)
        plt.show()
    elif k!=0 and k<S-1:
        e=patches.Arc((xcenter, ycenter), p[k], p[k], 0.0, theta[k-1]*(180/math.pi), theta[k]*(180/math.pi))
        ax.add_patch(e)
        num_ellipse.append(e)
    elif k==S-1:
        e=patches.Arc((xcenter, ycenter), p[k], p[k], 0.0, theta[k-1]*(180/math.pi), (2*math.pi/3)*(180/math.pi))
        ax.add_patch(e)
        num_ellipse.append(e)
    k=k+1

print num_ellipse
num_ellipse.remove(num_ellipse[0])
print num_ellipse
ax.add_patch(num_ellipse[0])
plt.show(block="True")
```

On running it produces the following output:

[image]

The problem here is that it is supposed to delete the first arc but it is not doing so. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing it from the list, does not remove it from the axis. You need to call `.remove` on the arc object. http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/artist_api.html

`num_ellipse[0].remove()`

You can check for the patches of the axis by calling

```
print ax.patches
num_ellipse.remove(num_ellipse[0])
print ax.patches #Still the same. 
ax.patches[0].remove()
print ax.patches #now it's gone
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked like a charm!

Comment: Okay so another problem, I tried to rotate the arc, now to do that I just change the starting and the ending angle by a small prefixed amount. The result is somewhat similar to the conundrum here. It forms a full circle. It should ideally delete the previous arc and then plot the new arc. Do you know how to solve this? If you want I can edit the question to add the new source code.

Comment: You would either have to remove the previous arc, pr update the parameters of the arc object that you already have.